# How to directly perform write.csv in R into tar.gz format?

Tags: r, csv, gzip, tar, in-memory

I have a big data.frame that I want to write into a compressed CSV file. Is there any way to directly write the data into a CSV.TAR.GZ compressed file instead of performing write.csv/gzip steps in order to reduce DISK access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `gzfile` (or `bzfile` for bzip2 archiving, or `xzfile` for xz archiving).

```
write.csv(mtcars, file=gzfile("mtcars.csv.gz"))
```

PS. If you only have one data frame, surely you don't need tar.

Comment: Thanks. Does it need a close()?

Comment: At least on Windows, no; and in fact, trying to do anything with the connection after the file has been written gives an error.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe, it is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: More concise writing. write.csv(mtcars, file=gzfile("mtcars.csv.gz"))

Comment: Can you please help me understand something regarding the line above?

I did the same, but my OS won't allow me to open the GZ file saying it is broken.

Error message: "Inappropriate file type or format."
OS is MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

It worked on the first try, but ever since I couldn't open a gz file written this way.