# R directly save data as zip file

Tags: r, zip, compression

I found `zip` and the `RCompression` package but can they do:

```
write.zip(x, file = "foo.zip")
```

as you'd with `write.csv`?

I'm also aware of `gzfile`.

Comment: Related to [How to directly perform write.csv in R into tar.gz format?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17492409/271616)

Comment: What does the help page say?

Comment: I take it it is not possible?

Comment: I believe I almost got it working: `zz <- unz(description="temp.csv.zip", filename="temp.csv")
open(zz)
not.a.DF <- readLines(zz)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's possible using gzip.

```
write.csv(mtcars, file=gzfile("mtcars.csv.gz"))
```

Comment: Using `write.csv` with .gz extension I got the maximum compression.

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished pretty easily using the readr functions and gzip.

```
library(readr)

write_tsv(mtcars, file.path(dir, "mtcars.tsv.gz"))

write_csv(mtcars, file.path(dir, "mtcars.csv.gz"))
```

From the docs, `?write_csv`:

> The `write_*()` functions will automatically compress outputs if an appropriate extension is given. Three extensions are currently supported: `.gz` for gzip compression, `.bz2` for bzip2 compression and `.xz` for lzma compression. See the examples for more information.